# How can I merge the data into SQL Server with bulk mode using execute DDL in mulesoft DB connector

Tags: sql-server

Below is the query I am using to merge the data.

```
<db:execute-ddl config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration_BW_DEV" doc:name="Database">
    <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[BEGIN MERGE STG_CRC_0PA_C01 AS DESTINO

USING(SELECT #[payload.EMPLOYEE]) AS FUENTE (EMPLOYEE) ON (DESTINO.EMPLOYEE = FUENTE.EMPLOYEE)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
       SET PERS_AREA = '#[payload.PERS_AREA]', 
           SURNAME = '#[payload.SURNAME]'

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (EMPLOYEE, PERS_AREA, SURNAME)
    VALUES (#[payload.EMPLOYEE],
            '#[payload.PERS_AREA]',
            '#[payload.SURNAME]'); END]]>
    </db:dynamic-query>
</db:execute-ddl>
```

This works fine for single record, but not for multiple records.

As I see do not see bulk mode for execute DDL operation.